# Restart a docker base image's CMD service

Tags: docker

**Background**

I have an image from here:
https://hub.docker.com/r/boostport/hbase-phoenix-all-in-one/tags?page=1&ordering=last_updated&name=1.2

This docker image's Dockerfile ends in the running of a bash script that starts alot of services. I need to change some of the services' configs. So, I have a Dockerfile that partially looks like this:

```
FROM boostport/hbase-phoenix-all-in-one:1.2-4.11
COPY ./my_configs.xml /opt/hbase/conf/hbase-site.xml
CMD ["./restart-hbase-phoenix.sh"]
```

Where the restart script simply restarts the services started in the CMD script from the parents image.

The issue I have is that my restart script seems to be run before the base image's services are running. I had assumed that the imaged would run first then my COPY and CMD would be run. This does not seem to be happening.

**Question**

How do I run a CMD only after the image is done with all of its Dockerfile commmands?

**Notes**

The errors:

```
stopping hbasecat: can't open '/tmp/hbase--master.pid': No such file or directory
no Query Server to stop because PID file not found, /tmp/phoenix/root-queryserver.pid
nothing to stop because no pid file /tmp/tephra-service-.pid
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a CMD command in your Dockerfile, that replaces the CMD commands of any of its base images. The CMD specifies what process runs in the container, and there can only be one. The latest declared one wins.

If all you need to do is start the processes, you can use the parent image's CMD by simply omitting CMD in your Dockerfile. If you need to make changes, copy the CMD from the base image and make the necessary changes.

Comment: useful one, Thnks!